# Retrieving local storage data?

Tags: javascript

I stored some card detail in localstorage, i get this cards details from javascript json variable. I want retrieve all cards details, when I alerting the first cards details it displaying the only the first letter of the first card.
  **the card data in javascript json variable**

```
 var cards =  [["Nixon", "McLean", "West Indies", 45, 314, 0, 1, "12.07", "37.58", 46, 3, 21, 8, "img/cards/7RBKWQPJAG_NixonMcLean.jpg", 1], ["Brian", "McMillan", "South Africa", 78, 841, 1, 0, "23.36", "36.98", 70, 4, 32, 43, "img/cards/Y9U5UKA60O_BrianMcMillan.jpg", 2], ["Craig", "McMillan", "New Zealand", 197, 4707, 3, 28, "28.18", "35.04", 49, 3, 20, 44, "img/cards/WE0NUNG80C_CraigMcMillan.jpg", 3]];
```

storing the card data:

```
 var user_arr=new Array();
     for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
                   {  
                      var userran=parseInt((Math.random() * (278 - 0+ 1)), 10) + 0;

                      user_arr.push(cards[userran]); 
                   }
     localStorage['userCard']=user_arr;
```

**when I alerting the first card data it gives only N of the cards variable , I want retrieve the all details of first card and individuals data first card.** how to retrieve local storage data please reply

```
  alert(localStorage['userCard'][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage stores the data in a string format.

You need to convert it to a string before saving it:

```
localStorage['userCard'] = JSON.stringify(user_arr);
```

and parse it before retrieving it:

```
var userArr = JSON.parse(localStorage['userCard']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s82zs/

Comment: @user3433253 Any time!